# Use R to perform a logistic regression and cross-validate in a small sample?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, cross-validation, regression-strategies

I have a small sample (n=69, 35 with diseases, 34 without disease). I have around 20 variables that came up as significant using indiscriminate univariate regression. Of these 20 variables, several are already known to be associated with the disease.

I have 3 other variables that are also significant but are novel measurements from this study.

My questions are

1. How do I choose variables that I need to include to get the most parsimonious model? Are there R packages that will help do this, or should I "pick and choose"?
2. Can I cross-validate in such a small sample? If so, again, what method would I use?

Comment: You will need to do a lot of study to understand the issues here, and unfortunately will not find your sample useful for the intended purpose.  It requires 96 subjects just to estimate the intercept in a logistic regression model (zero variables!)  and even then the margin of error is not great.  See my RMS course notes: http://www.fharrell.com/p/blog-page.html .  If you elect to proceed you will be shocked at the poor validation when you use the best available method (the optimism bootstrap).

Comment: Correct link is https://hbiostat.org/rms